# AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat not working with mp3 Java

Tags: java, mp3, jlayer, audioinputstream, tritonus

I am trying to convert an mp3 file into Audio Input Stream with Java. Following is the portion of my code.

```
 **File file = new File("/root/Desktop/files/Song1.mp3");
        AudioFileFormat baseFileFormat = null;
        AudioFormat baseFormat = null;
        baseFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
        baseFormat = baseFileFormat.getFormat();
        AudioFileFormat.Type type = baseFileFormat.getType();
        float frequency = baseFormat.getSampleRate();
        System.out.println("Sample Rate: " + baseFormat.getSampleRate());
        System.out.println("Frame Size: " + baseFormat.getFrameSize());
        System.out.println("Frame Rate: " + baseFormat.getFrameRate());
        System.out.println("Sample Size In Bits: " + baseFormat.getSampleSizeInBits());
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);**
```

I have included the following Jars: 
jl1.0.1.jar, tritonus_share.jar, mp3spi1.9.5.jar

I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: 
>   `file is not a supported file type`.

Any sort of help in this regards would be appreciated.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: greg-449 I am getting the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type

Comment: What O.S are you compiling this on? I wonder why `/root/Desktop/files/` and not something like `c:/root/Desktop/files/` for example

Comment: I am using centos 6.7